# Machine learning development environment

Tags: python, r, haskell, machine-learning

I use python for doing prototypes in machine learning but have often been frustrated with the slow interpreter. Is there a language which is good for prototype (enough libraries like sklearn, numpy, scipy) but at the same time is fast and is a powerful language.

What I am looking for is something that I can prototype in and deploy in production as well. What do people commonly use ?

Comment: (+1) @PaulHiemstra, I stopped reading the question after that :)

Comment: @e4e5f4 May be my comment came out too strong. How much does R compare against python in terms of language features: Object oriented, parallel processing etc?

Comment: @IJ If you don't know then how can you claim that R is not a real language in the first place! I do not know enough about Python to comment comprehensively on your query.

Comment: Too generic/opinion-based question. A quick google search for `R oject oriented programming` gives many relevant results. For parallel processing etc. have a look at this page - http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: Looks like you are too biased towards R :-). I didn't want to pitch this as a python vs R thread. I was looking for a language where you could easily implement a machine learning paper, not use an existing package (something that I have to do frequently). With python I often stumble into the slow interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Python is as good as it gets if you want a real language with lots of libraries.

MATLAB is probably the most popular commercial solution for prototyping. It has numerous built-ins and is easy to handle. In terms of performance, MATLAB is currently king in prototyping, second only to compiled languages for production (C, Fortran, C++, ...). It's not a proper language, though, so I guess this isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: Why downrate? What I wrote is true and helpful, matlab is immensely popular for prototyping. It's worth including in the list. I am not advertising or anything since I specifically mentioned it does not meet all criteria proposed by the question. If speed is the main concern in Python, the only better alternative that I know of is matlab (assuming the Python code is written properly).

Answer (score 2):

Python is pretty much as good as it gets for the sort of prototyping you describe. However, I have to ask, if you're frustrated with its speed as a numeric language: how are you writing your code? The way to do this in Python is with [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which is a package for numerical computing where the underlying operations on arrays (matrices) are performed using compiled C code. It does mean learning how to express your computations as matrix operations however, so if you're not used to linear algebra/matrix manipulation then it might require a bit of getting used to. It's basically a Matlab-like environment.

My experience: if you're writing your python code using a lot of loops, element-wise operations, etc. it is slow and ugly. Once you learn the equivalent Numpy/Scipy way, the speed gains are phenomenal (and what you write is much closer to the mathematical expression too).

Answer (score 1):

You can use R within Python [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/). This way you can use R functionalities within a python program for further usage.

Depending on what you want to do, you can also have a look on [OpenCV Python](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/), for lower level machine learning tools (SVM ...)

Comment: ...the OP specifically requested no R.

Comment: No R because of limitations of the language, but in combination with another language like python it can become much powerful

Comment: When you say R functionalities, do you mean using R packages ?

Comment: Yes. RPy comes as a python package that allows you to use R functions within a python program. Check out this [example](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy_demo.html)